# How to deal with error "dial tcp 10.240.0.4:10250: i/o timeout" to see pod's logs in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, timeout, kubectl, azure-aks

Before I could run this command `kubectl logs <pod>` without issue for many days/versions. However, after I pushed another image and deployed recently, I faced below error:

> Error from server: Get https://aks-agentpool-xxx-0:10250/containerLogs/default/<-pod->/<-service->: dial tcp 10.240.0.4:10250: i/o timeout

I tried to re-build and re-deploy but failed.

Below was the Node info for reference:
[image: Node Info]

Comment: i dont think has anything to do with the build. try redownloading kubectl config

Comment: hi @4c74356b41, but when I logged in to another subscription's AKS, I could see the logs

Comment: redownload the kubectl config

Comment: hi @4c74356b41, may you share commands to me to redownload kubectl config?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster it will show you the sample

Comment: I tried to run below commands but still fails:  
1. `az aks install-cli`  
2. `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <-ResourceGroup-> --name <-AKS->`  
3. checked still have timeout error  
4. delete file in **/Users/<-user->/.kube/config**  
5. `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <-ResourceGroup-> --name <-AKS->`  
  
Still not okay.

Comment: Which region does the AKS cluster in?

Comment: It is in East Asia

Comment: Do you check if there is any problem with the AKS cluster node?

Comment: @CharlesXu, added Node Info for your reference by running `kubecel describe nodes` before.

Comment: Does it help  you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your issue is caused by the problem described in this [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-cant-get-logs-by-using-kubectl-logs-or-i-cant-connect-to-the-api-server-im-getting-error-from-server-error-dialing-backend-dial-tcp-what-should-i-do). But maybe you can take a try, it shows below:

> Make sure that the default network security group isn't modified and
> that both port 22 and 9000 are open for connection to the API server.
> Check whether the `tunnelfront` pod is running in the `kube-system`
> namespace using the `kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system` command.
> If it isn't, force deletion of the pod and it will restart.

Comment: In my case, deleting/restarting `tunnelfront` pod worked fine.