# Deploying a stateless Go app with Redis on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-go-client

I had deploy a stateless Go web app with Redis on Kubernetes. Redis pod is running fine but the main issue with application pod and getting error **dial tcp: i/o timeout** in log. Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: share deployment yaml files. What does this go application does?

Comment: thank you Arghya for reply. I had followed this https://www.callicoder.com/deploy-multi-container-go-redis-app-kubernetes/  blog.

Comment: It is basically hitting one public API hosted at http://quotes.rest/ , then it caches the result in Redis until the end of the day. For subsequent API calls, the app will return the result from Redis cache instead of fetching it from the public API.

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox ?

Comment: I am using Azure Virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

Please take look: [aks-vm-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866030/azure-kubernetes-how-can-i-deal-with-error-dial-tcp-10-240-0-410250-i-o-time).

> Make sure that the default network security group isn't modified and that both port 22 and 9000 are open for connection to the API server. Check whether the tunnelfront pod is running in the kube-system namespace using the kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system command.
>   If it isn't, force deletion of the pod and it will restart.

Also make sure if Redis port is open.

More info about troubleshooting: [dial-backend-troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-cant-get-logs-by-using-kubectl-logs-or-i-cant-connect-to-the-api-server-im-getting-error-from-server-error-dialing-backend-dial-tcp-what-should-i-do).

**EDIT:**

Answering on your question about tunnelfront:

`tunnelfront` is an AKS system component that's installed on every cluster that helps to facilitate secure communication from your hosted Kubernetes control plane and your nodes. It's needed for certain operations like kubectl exec, and will be redeployed to your cluster on version upgrades.

Speaking about VM:

I would SSH into the it and start watching the disk IO latency using bpf / bcc tools and the docker / kubelet logs.

Comment: Hi @MaggieO , i had deploy this application on Azure virtual machine worker node.Tested the same application on aks and it is working fine. I think there is a issue in my virtual machine's kubernetes cluster.

Comment: what is the use of tunnelfront pod in the cluster @MaggieO