# Azure AKS - dial tcp <private-ip>:10250: i/o timeout

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I'm getting the below error when trying to run kubectl logs :
dial tcp :10250: i/o timeout

Running get pods/describe works fine, it is only when I try to get logs that I receive this error. I have tried restarting the cluster/tunnelfront pod etc. to no avail. Does anyone know what could be causing or what I can check in the cluster to help resolve?

Thanks,

Comment: Please check this it may helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866030/how-to-deal-with-error-dial-tcp-10-240-0-410250-i-o-timeout-to-see-pods-log

Comment: Hello @adan11, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you –

Answer (score 0):

your issue may caused by the problem described in this [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#im-receiving-tcp-timeouts-such-as-dial-tcp-node_ip10250-io-timeout). But maybe you can try the below solution which is provided in Microsoft Document.

These timeouts may be related to internal traffic between nodes being blocked. Verify that this traffic is not being blocked, such as by [network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-security#azure-network-security-groups) on the subnet for your cluster's nodes.