# Cannot check the log from pods after upgrade kubernetes version

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

Before I could use `kubectl logs devops2-pdf-xxx` to check the log of the pods.
But after I upgraded the `kubectl` version, I could not do that. Thus, seems the service is not running well.

But when I run `kubectl describe node`, the resource allocation is less than 100%.

`kubectl logs xxx`:

```
Error from server: Get "https://aks-agentpool-123456-1:10250/containerLogs/default/devops2-deployment-123456-456/devops2-pdf": dial tcp 10.240.0.5:10250: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to solve this problem. It is probably related to a closed port:

- First, check that your port 10250 is open. Similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089581/error-from-server-dial-tcp-i-o-timeout-error-when-getting-logs-of-pod)
- You are using AKS, so check solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866030/how-to-deal-with-error-dial-tcp-10-240-0-410250-i-o-timeout-to-see-pods-log):

> Make sure that the default network security group isn't modified and that both port 22 and 9000 are open for connection to the API server. Check whether the `tunnelfront` pod is running in the `kube-system` namespace using the `kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system` command. If it isn't, force deletion of the pod and it will restart.

You can also check official Microsoft [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#im-receiving-tcp-timeouts-such-as-dial-tcp-node_ip10250-io-timeout)

> These timeouts may be related to internal traffic between nodes being blocked. Verify that this traffic is not being blocked, such as by [network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-security#azure-network-security-groups) on the subnet for your cluster's nodes.

or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#im-receiving-tcp-timeouts-when-using-kubectl-or-other-third-party-tools-connecting-to-the-api-server).